Is it possible to use pip install tensorflow[and-cuda] in Conda?
I am trying to follow the official tensorflow pip installation steps to install tensorflow supporting GPU with cuda in a conda environment as specified here.
And after installation, the tensorflow in Python doesn't pickup the GPU correctly.
mamba install cuda

pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]

pip's path is /opt/conda/bin/pip
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
[]

Does anyone know how to fix it using pip installation?
I know if I install tensorflow-gpu via conda as specified here, everything works fine.
And my question why pip in that case is not working properly in a conda environment.
And I also notice that compared to Tensorflow, Pytorch official websites has support for conda cuda installation, however this is not in tensorflow official website. Is there some historical reasons for this? Any information or idea on this are welcome, and also ways to fix pip installation of tensorflow in conda environment is welcome.
Thanks in advance!

which GPU do you have and what is your nvidia driver version?

A10 and driver version is 535.161.07

Just a side note: Tensorflow has no official conda builds, that is why it is not mentioned in the docs. The reason seems to be a lack of devs that could maintain them, see this github issue.

The builds that are available from the anaconda channels are maintained by continuum/anaconda and conda-forge is maintained by community efforts. Both should provide reliable and safe builds of tensorflow

You probably need to do mamba install -c nvidia cudatoolkit cudnn in you environment when you want to pip install
